# How to get random sample out of a table data that has selective number of variables in a column out of all the variables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

> The below query is the one I have used to get random sample of 50,000 rows of a table, by limiting the 50,000 rows only to 7 variables in column2, which are 'zzz', 'xxxx', 'yyyy', 'hhhh', 'ggggg','kkkk','ooo'. But the below query is not working quite good as it is randomly selecting variables amongst the 7 variables and only displaying 2 or 3 variables for the most part. **I would like the query to changed in such a way that it shows a 50,000 rows random sample that has all 7 variables in it**

```
 select top 50000 v.column1, v.column2, v.column3, v.column 4

 from (select top 40 percent distinct  ceo.column1, ceo.column2,cm.column 3, cm.column4

  from table1 ceo 

  inner join table2 cm  on cm.column1 = ceo.column1

  where isnumeric(ceo.column1) !=0

  and column2 IN ('zzz', 'xxxx', 'yyyy', 'hhhh', 'ggggg','kkkk','ooo'

  Order by newid()))v
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution could be an union all

```
SELECT * from 
(select top 7000 .... where column2 = 'zzz' ORDER BY newID()) A
union all 
SELECT * from
(select top 7000 .... where column2 = 'xxxx'  ORDER BY newID()) B
```

From a performance perspective, you could also tak in consideration 
SELECT FROM table1 TABLESAMPLE (7000 ROWS)

Comment: thanks for the response. I tried this way ,but I am getting a "deadlock" error in this method. Because in reality I have 63 variables to handle not 7 variables as shown in the example.

Comment: It's very rare that a select, outside of a transaction, results in deadlock. It would be interesting to see the deadlock graph. In the meantime, have you tried with "SET TRANSACTION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITED" OR WITH NOLOCK ?

Comment: Can you please let me know how/where to insert the "SET TRANSACTION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITED" OR WITH NOLOCK ?" in the query.  Thanks.

Comment: Just write it before the script. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql

Comment: WITH (NOLOCK) is a table hint. You have to write just after the table name. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select column1, column2, column3, column4
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by column2 order by newid()) as seqnum
      from t
      where column2 in ('zzz', 'xxxx', 'yyyy', 'hhhh', 'ggggg', 'kkkk', 'ooo')
     ) t
where seqnum <= 50000;
```

Your question mentions one table but your code has more than one table -- making the question a bit unclear.  However, the same logic would work for a `join` query in the subquery.